# Instantiating a Variable

Tags: c++

I have two classes. My main class `CPlotView:CScrollView` and another class `CAnimateMachine`. The main class has a few drawing functions, namely simple animation. I have modeled the animation as a state machine. To aid in keeping the state machine in line I created the second class. My issue is trying to instantiate an instance of the second class.

In `PlotView` I have a variable `CAnimateMachine m_AniMach;` in the header. After some actions take place a function `AniInit()` is called to initialize the state machine object. I currently am trying to do this with this line `m_AniMach = CAnimateMachine()` but am receiving a C2248 error `'CObject::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'`.

When `AniInit()` is called I want to just re-instantiate a completely new `CAnimateMachine` object and initialize the variables based on the current state of `CPlotView`.

Here is an succinct version of `CAnimateMachine` and the classes it utilizes.

```
class  CMoveBlk : public CObject
{
    // ints and floats
}

class CSheetData : public CObject
{
    // ints and floats
    CTypedPtrList<CObList, CMoveBlk*> m_MoveList;
}

class CAnimateMachine
{
public:
    CAnimateMachine(); // Not implemented

    int startX;
    int startY;
    float lastX; 
    float lastY;

    POSITION curShtPos;
    POSITION curBlkPos;
    CMoveBlk *curMoveBlk;
    CSheetData *curShtData;

    CPen myPen1;
    CPen myPen2;
    CPen myPen3;
};
```

Here is my complete `AniInit` method. The very first line is the one that throws the error.

```
BOOL CPlotView::AnimateInit()
{
    m_AniMach = CAnimateMachine();

    // Get the Document containing the sheet information
    CPlotDoc* pDoc = (CPlotDoc*)GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (pDoc->m_nCurSheet == 0)
        return FALSE; 

    // Get the actual information we need
    m_AniMach.sheetPos = pDoc->m_SheetList.FindIndex(pDoc->m_nCurSheet - 1);
    if (m_AniMach.sheetPos == NULL) 
        return FALSE;
    m_AniMach.curShtData = pDoc->m_SheetList.GetAt(m_AniMach.sheetPos);
    if (m_AniMach.curShtData == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    // Erase the current drawing/background
    CDC *pDC = GetDC();
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    pDC->DPtoLP(&rect); 
    pDC->FillSolidRect( &rect, GetBackgroundColor());

    // Set the start position
    m_AniMach.startX = (int)(m_AniMach.curShtData->m_fStartX * m_fScaleX + 0.5) + m_nOffsetX;
    m_AniMach.startY = (int)(m_AniMach.curShtData->m_fStartY * m_fScaleY + 0.5) + m_nOffsetY;

    m_AniMach.lastX = m_AniMach.curShtData->m_fStartX;
    m_AniMach.lastY = m_AniMach.curShtData->m_fStartY;

    // Get the current Block
    m_AniMach.curBlkPos = m_AniMach.curShtData->m_MoveList.GetHeadPosition();

    // Create all of the pens used to draw
    m_AniMach.myPen1.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0,0,0));
    m_AniMach.myPen2.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0,0,0));
    m_AniMach.myPen3.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0,0,0));

    return TRUE;
}
```

What I suspect the issue is based on the error, is with my two pointers in the `CAnimateMachine` class that point to `CSheetData : CObject` and `CMoveBlk : CObject`. I am just not sure why the issue is there, I think it should just create the pointers and have them point to nothing until I assign them in `AniInit()`?

Comment: The copy assignment operator in `CObject` is private and cannot be accessed. Don't call the `CObject::operator=` from the derived classes assignment operator. If the copy assignment operator in the derived class is defaulted provide an implementation (if possible).

Comment: So I should create an overloaded = operator for `CAnimateMachine`?

Comment: Can't say without knowing why the base class declares the operator private. There may be very good reasons to prevent copying objects. Refer to the documentation for that class to determine if that's the way to progress.

Comment: I don't want to copy any information (there actually is none to even copy), I just want to instantiate the variable anew. I want to "erase" `m_AniMach` and re-initialize it with the `AniInit()` method. So no data is to be copied, and no data can be copied; I never refer to another `CAnimateMachine` object other than the one the constructor returns in `AniInit()`. // With that being said, do you think the solution is to overload the = operator and just have the body be `return CAnimateObject();`?

Comment: _"I just want to instantiate the variable anew"_ - it's already initialized. If you want to change it after it's been constructed your best bet is to provide an appropriate copy assignment operator. If that is not an option stop using multi-phase initialization and initialize everything in the constructor _or_ use aggregation instead of composition.

Comment: Could you link me to a site that explains aggregation vs composition? I've never heard of those terms. // Is an object not allowed to change once it has been constructed? Like if I have a variable `Rectangle rect`, is it not right to do `rect.left = 10;`? Should I construct a new `Rectangle` in that case?